# Creation of proxy objects in GWT RequestFactory

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Is it possible to create a proxy object in the client code without using any request context?

I want this behavior because I want to send the object to the server multiple times and I cant do so if its associated to single request context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your proxy with one `RequestContext` and send it. Once the response is received, the object is *frozen* and no longer attached to a `RequestContext`, you can thus send it with another `RequestContext` (as before, you'll have to wait for the response before being able to use it yet another `RequestContext`).

I'll investigate if these constraints can be relaxed in a future version of GWT.